# Github Pages not found when reloading

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I made a react js website and published it on my github page. I named the project sleepypower.github.io so it didn't have any additional info and be easier to write.

However, when I go to a page let's say sleepypower.github.io/page, and reload it, it says page not found

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Github pages server intercepts the URL pathname first and responds with 404. So you might have to go extra steps to make react routing work with Github pages. I suggest following this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/